# How does one create a package for a Java Project through the Unix command-line?

Tags: java

How does one create a package for a Java Project through the Unix command-line?

I am looking to find a way to create a package for my Java files similar to the way Eclipse does, but in the command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaging is internal to your code; you don't need any external tools. All you need to do is insert a `package your.package.name;` declaration at the top of each `.java` file, and stick them all in a `/your/package/name` directory (generally under the `src` dir of your project), and they'll be packaged.

Answer (score 2):

The package structure is merely a directory structure. So I would use

```
mkdir -p com/oopsconsultancy/example
vi com/oopsconsultancy/example/Example.java
```

The `Example.java` would have to have the appropriate `package` statement inserted automatically (I had a vim plugin for this ages ago)